# RESTSharp has problems deserializing XML including Byte Order Mark?

Tags: c#, restsharp, byte-order-mark

There is a public webservice which I want to use in a short C# Application:
http://ws.parlament.ch/

The returned XML from this webservice has a "BOM" at the beginning, which causes RESTSharp to fail the deserializing of the XML with the following error message:

> Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info. --->
>   System.Xml.XmlException: **Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1,
>   position 1.**    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
>   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()    at
>   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options) 
>   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
>   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text)    at
>   RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer.Deserialize[T](IRestResponse
>   response)    at RestSharp.RestClient.Deserialize[T](IRestRequest
>   request, IRestResponse raw)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Here is an easy sample by using http://ws.parlament.ch/sessions?format=xml to get a List of '*Sessions*':

```
public class Session
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
    public int? Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime? From { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? To { get; set; }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
        request.Resource = "sessions";
        request.AddParameter("format", "xml");

        var client = new RestClient("http://ws.parlament.ch/");
        var response = client.Execute<List<Session>>(request);

        if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            const string message = "Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.";
            var ex = new ApplicationException(message, response.ErrorException);
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        List<Session> test = response.Data;

        Console.Read();
    }
```

When I first manipulate the returned xml with Fiddler to remove the first 3 bits (the "BOM"), the above code works! May someone please help me to handle this directly in RESTSharp? What am I doing wrong? THANK YOU in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the Solution - Thank you @arootbeer for the hints!

Instead of wrapping the XMLDeserializer, you can also use the 'RestRequest.OnBeforeDeserialization' event from #RESTSharp. So you just need to insert something like this after the new RestRequest() (see my initial code example) and then it works perfect!

```
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp =>
            {
                //remove the first ByteOrderMark
                //see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663100/restsharp-has-problems-deserializing-xml-including-byte-order-mark
                string byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
                if (resp.Content.StartsWith(byteOrderMarkUtf8))
                    resp.Content = resp.Content.Remove(0, byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length);
            };
```

Comment: Glad I could help. I like the simplicity of the solution.

Comment: This would *not* work!! Try this to see why:

`var preamble = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble();

var preambleString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(preamble);

var message = new byte[] { 60, 63, 120, 109, 108, 32 }; // "<?xml "

var messageString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);


Console.WriteLine(preamble);

Console.WriteLine(preambleString.Length);

Console.WriteLine(messageString);

Console.WriteLine(messageString.StartsWith(preambleString));`

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, but not specifically with RestSharp. Use this:

```
var responseXml = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetString(bytes);
```

Original discussion: [XmlReader breaks on UTF-8 BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104158/xmlreader-breaks-on-utf-8-bom)

Pertinent quote from the answer:

> The xml string must not (!) contain the BOM, the BOM is only allowed in byte data (e.g. streams) which is encoded with UTF-8. This is because the string representation is not encoded, but already a sequence of unicode characters.

Edit:
Looking through their docs, it looks like the most straightforward way to handle this (aside from a GitHub issue) is to call the non-generic  `Execute()` method and deserialize the response from that string. You could also create an `IDeserializer` that wraps the default XML deserializer.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I use this with RESTSharp?

Answer (score 2):

The [solution that @dataCore posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19683494/11633714) doesn't quite work, but this one should.

```
request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => {
    if (resp.RawBytes.Length >= 3 && resp.RawBytes[0] == 0xEF && resp.RawBytes[1] == 0xBB && resp.RawBytes[2] == 0xBF)
    {
        // Copy the data but with the UTF-8 BOM removed.
        var newData = new byte[resp.RawBytes.Length - 3];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(resp.RawBytes, 3, newData, 0, newData.Length);
        resp.RawBytes = newData;

        // Force re-conversion to string on next access
        resp.Content = null;
    }
};
```

Setting `resp.Content` to `null` is there as a safety guard, as `RawBytes` is only converted to a string if `Content` isn't already set to a value.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work with RestSharp you can parse response content manually and remove all the "funny" characters coming before the '<'.

```
var firstChar = responseContent[0];

// removing any 'funny' characters coming before '<'
while (firstChar != 60)
{
    responseContent= responseContent.Remove(0, 1);
    firstChar = responseContent[0];
}

XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(responseContent));
```