# Deserializing UTF-8 encoded XML fails when BOM is present

Tags: c#, xml, utf-8, deserialization

I have a really weird issue here: I'm building an interface to a third-party system which provides XML files (with a UTF-8 encoding) over a SFTP server.

I download those files in my C# code, and then I try to deserialize them into a C# object. For most of the files, this works quite nicely, but for some, it just keeps bombing out....

Imagine a DTO class like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and a XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
    <Age>42</Age>
</Person>
```

What I'm doing on my side in my C# code is:

- download the file content as a byte array from the SFTP server
- extract an UTF-8 encoded string from that binary data
- use that string representation for the deserialization process

Something like this:

```
// get bytes from SFTP server
byte[] content = _sftpClient.Download(fileName);

// convert content to a UTF-8 string
string contentAsString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(content);

try
{
    // deserialize that string into a "Person" instance
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.IgnoreComments = true;
    settings.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
    settings.CheckCharacters = false;

    using (StringReader str = new StringReader(contentAsString))
    using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(str, settings))
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));

        if (ser.CanDeserialize(xr))
        {
            Person person = ser.Deserialize(xr) as Person;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0} - {1}", exc.GetType().Name, exc.Message);
}
```

Now I analyzed the files that worked, and those that didn't - and the difference is a three-byte prefix in the binary data (`0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`) - the "Unicode BOM" (Byte-Order Mark).

I am aware of that BOM, and that's the reason I'm not using the **binary** data fetched from the SFTP Server directly. When I convert those types of files into the XML string `contentAsString`, this string *appears* to be identical - at least I can't see any difference at all.

But the files with the 3-byte BOM at the beginning (in the binary data) cause the deserialization to fail on this line

```
if (ser.CanDeserialize(xr))
```

with an error:

> SystemException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

But how on earth does the **string** know / "preserve" that information about the 3-byte BOM? I was expecting that by turning the byte array into a  UTF-8 encoded string, any differences would go away and the BOM should no longer be relevant...

Any ideas on how I can reliably deal with both files *with* or *without* the 3-byte BOM?

Comment: Possible duplicate - check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104158/xmlreader-breaks-on-utf-8-bom

Comment: @hoodaticus it's not quite a duplicate - yes, the situation seems to be almost the same - but the accepted response is actually what I'm doing already, and it's **not working** for me (causes an exception if the BOM is present). That proposed solution is not solving my issue, unfortunately.....

Comment: _BOMbing out_ I see what you did there :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating a `string` from the byte[] and use that as the input for the XmlReader, use a `MemoryStream`:

```
        // get bytes from SFTP server
        byte[] content = _sftpClient.Download(fileName);

        try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.IgnoreComments = true;
            settings.IgnoreProcessingInstructions = true;
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
            settings.CheckCharacters = false;

            using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(content))
            using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(memoryStream, settings))
            {
                XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));

                if (ser.CanDeserialize(xr))
                {
                    Person person = ser.Deserialize(xr) as Person;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0} - {1}", exc.GetType().Name, exc.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm amazed this works - I was **convinced** I needed to convert the byte array to a string to get rid of the differences with or without the BOM - but in the end, it's actually the other way around - using the byte stream directly works, using the "intermediary" string doesn't ..... but it works - so thanks a heap !