# Correcting Encoding in a large Xml File

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, xml-parsing

I'm importing data from XML files containing this type of content:

`<FirstName>™MšR</FirstName><MiddleName/><LastName>HšNER™Z</LastName>`

The XML is loaded via:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

 try
 {
      doc.Load(fullFilePath);
 }
```

When I execute this code with the data contained on top I get an exception about an illegal character.  I understand that part just fine.

I'm not sure which encoding this is or how to solve this problem.  Is there a way I can change the encoding of the XmlDocument or another method to make sure the above content is parsed correctly?

---

Update: I do not have any encoding declaration or `<?xml` in this document.

I've seen some links say to add it dynamically?  Is this UTF-16 encoding?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that:

- The name was `ÖMÜR HÜNERÖZ` (or possibly `ÔMÜR HÜNERÔZ` or `ÕMÜR HÜNERÕZ`; I don't know what language that is).
- The XML file was encoded using the DOS "OEM" code page, probably 437 or 850.
- But it was decoded using windows-1252 (the "ANSI" code page).

Comment: Good catch! I'd only looked at the 125x code pages -- totally forgot about the DOS ones... I'll add some more info to my reply.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the file with a hex editor ([HXD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) or Visual Studio, for instance), what exactly do you see?

Is every character from the string you posted represented by a single byte? Does the file have a byte-order mark (a bunch of non-printable bytes at the start of the file)?

The ™ and š seem to indicate that something went pretty wrong with encoding/conversion along the way, but let's see... I guess they both correspond with a vowel (**O**-M-**A**-R H-**A**-NER-**O**-Z, maybe?), but I haven't figured out yet how they ended up looking like this...

**Edit**: [dan04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454049/correcting-encoding-in-a-large-xml-file/4456624#4456624) hit the nail on the head. `™` in [cp-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1252) has hex value 99, and `š` is 9a. In [cp-437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) and [cp-850](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), hex 99 represents `Ö`, and 9a `Ü`.

The fix is simple: just specify this encoding when opening your XML file:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.GetEncoding(437)))
{
   doc.Load(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581318/c-detect-xml-encoding-from-byte-array):

```
Encoding encoding;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    using (var xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(stream))
    {
        xmlreader.MoveToContent();
        encoding = xmlreader.Encoding;
    }
}
```

You might want to take a look at this: [How to best detect encoding in XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637855/how-to-best-detect-encoding-in-xml-file)

For actual reading you can use [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bc2hwcb.aspx) to take care of BOM(Byte order mark):

```
string xml;

using (var reader = new StreamReader("FilePath", true))
{                                   //            ↑ 
    xml= reader.ReadToEnd();       //        detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks
}
```

**Edit:** Removed the encoding parameter. StreamReader will detect the encoding of a file if the file contains a BOM. If it does not it will default to UTF8.

**Edit 2**: [Detecting Text Encoding for StreamReader](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/197245.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you provided a fragment of the XML document since it's missing a root element, so I'll assume that was your intention.  Is there an xml processing instruction at the top like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`?